# Getting rid of the #038; when string replacing content

Tags: customization

I'm trying to add some string replacements to the_title() -

```
function format_title($content) {
    $content = str_replace('&','&<br>', $content);
    $content = str_replace('!','!<br>', $content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_title','format_title',11);
```

When I try and replace ampersands I get an additional "#038;" after the replacement (ASCII for ampersand), I'm not sure as to why this occurs (security reason?) or how to create a workaround. I've tried replacing "&" with "& amp ;" but with no effect.

The goal is to add line breaks at certain points of a title to create a better flow in the typography.
Both the database and the site has UTF8 encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&#38;` is essentially synonym of `&amp;`. In `the_title` filter [`wptexturize()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize) runs with priority `1` (important!) and makes this replacement.

So by the time it gets to your `format_title()` at priority `11` - instead of replacing lone `&` symbol you replace (and break) chunk of `&#38;` character entity.

So you can:

1. move your function to priority `0` and it will run before texturize
2. leave priority at `11` but replace `$#38;` instead of just `&`

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused by `esc_url`. You should use `esc_url_raw` instead, in this scenario.

`esc_url` has this piece of code:

```php
// Replace ampersands and single quotes only when displaying.
if ( $_context === 'display' ) {
    $url = wp_kses_normalize_entities( $url );
    $url = str_replace( '&amp;', '&#038;', $url ); <!-- See this line!
    $url = str_replace( "'", '&#039;', $url );
}
```

What `esc_url_raw` does is simply calling `esc_url` and skipping that conditional by passing a different context as argument.

Answer (score -2):

Here is one more solution:-

```
wp-includes\formatting.php >> esc_url ()  >>  comment the line <br> $url = str_replace( '&amp;', '&#038;', $url );
```

It works for me.

Comment: Never edit the core, even if it works! Your changes may not stay upon next update!